# Angular 4 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

In a very large project web I still working on my company, some errors occurs while I testing the development version in the browser (Chrome and Firefox).
Someone can help me?

// update the message on screen

```
    this.parametrosMensagemService.setMessage(this.alert)
    this.pagerService.items = this.pagerService.items.filter(x => x.selecionado == "checked")
    this.setPage(1)
```

[Error log in Chrome Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vt9rt.png)

Comment: because `this.pagerService.items` is not defined.

Comment: Infact property `items` doesn't exist in `this.pagerService`. <--- Error says

Answer (score 2):

Becasue property `items` doesn't exist on `this.pageService`.

To avoid this error try to add some checks for better practice like -

```
this.pagerService.items = this.pagerService && this.pagerService.items && this.pagerService.items.filter(x => x.selecionado == "checked")
```